IAM policy update failed: domain restriction organization policy
I have deployed a cloud function (gen-2) and trying to set it to be publicly available.
To achieve this, I am setting "Authentication" to "Allow unauthenticated invocations" in Cloud Run --> Security --> Allow unauthenticated invocations
but when i save this settings, i face the following error:

IAM policy update failed
A domain restriction organization policy is in place. Only principals
in allowed domains can be added as principals in the policy. Correct
the principal emails and try again.

Please advise.

Ask your GCP admin to whitelist your project. However, be aware of the impacts to make a service public. Your sec team can challenge on the different way you will secure a public service and what you envision.
